# Png Transparency in graphics32, Builder XE6

Tags: png, c++builder, graphics32

I would like to use Png images while working in C++ Builder RAD Studio XE6. I am using graphics32 lib and I managed to install runtime and designtime packages. I can put the TImage32 component on my form, then I load the png image in TImage32, but instead of transparency, I get white color on the background. I just cant see what do I have to do, to get transparent png image on my form.

I would be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Graphics32 does not support any other format than Bitmap (BMP). In order to use the PNG format its necessary to use an additional library, especially when you want to maintain full transparency information.

One of these libraries that was meant to work hand in hand with Graphics32 is [GR32PNG](https://github.com/graphics32/GR32PNG). However, this library is not meant to be used at design time for various reasons. One of these is the fact that even with an available design time package, Graphics32 was never designed to support any other format than Bitmap (*.bmp). Thus, it would be required to rewrite parts of Graphics32 to support other formats (which hasn't been done so far).

Alternatively, it should be possible to use the built-in support of XE6 to load PNG files. This won't be design time either (for the same reasons) and sometimes it doesn't handle transparency properly. Not to mention the fact that it converts the image to TImage before, which typically doubles the required amount of memory during loading.

Comment: Yesterday I got in trouble while searching for solution for transparent png in graphics32. I did something wrong, and now when I put Image321 on the form and try to load a file (Image321->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("rabbit.png");) -- I get Access violation at address 501608E6 in module 'rtl200.bpl'. Read of address 003A004F. I tried to install graphics32 again, but the problem with access violation in module rtl200.bpl persists. So unfortunatelly , I can not try the gr32png library at the moment. Any advice?

Comment: It's not supported to load a PNG file with Image321->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("rabbit.png"); It would assume that rabbit.png is a bitmap which might be the reason for the access violation.

Comment: When I load the image into Image321 from Object Inspector, everything seems to work. But when I try to load image from application,  I get the AViolation message no matter what file format the image has.( Even if I try  Image321->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("rabbit.bmp"); - 32 bit bitmap ). I reinstalled Rad XE6 and graphics32, the same problem stays. Is it possible that I did something to windows OS?

Comment: Actually C++ Builder is not widely tested with Graphics32 so it might be that there is still a bug somewhere. With Delphi there hasn't been any bug report so far.
Please try to debug this as good as possible and post an issue on the Graphics32 GitHub page.

Comment: I managed to install one of your previous versions of GR32, with packages RSXE5 and DSGN RSXE5 and the problem with loading an image luckily dissapeared. I tried to get png transpareny, so in project manager  I add GR_32Png.pas and GR32_PortableNetworkGraphics.pas (form your GR32PNGmaster ) to the project. Compiler asks for all GR32 dcu files so I add them to project folder. After compiling, I still get unknown picture file extension (.png), when trying to load the image. Hmmmm?

Comment: Actually all you need is to include GR32_Png and use LoadBitmap32FromPNG(Image321->Bitmap, "rabbit.png") in order to load the png. As mentioned in the answer, it's not possible to load anything else than a bitmap (*.bmp) directly with GR32.

Comment: I have been "away" for 10 days. Thanks for answer - I will try it in the week end.

Comment: Well I added #include "GR32_Png.hpp" in the header, after adding and compiling GR32_Png.pas file in the project. Still I get unknown picture file extension (png). I tried with GraphicEx lib, it works and now I can load png images. I Just dont know what am I doing wrong with GR32_Png.... Your GR32 is really usefull for me (http://www.borutkorosec.net/) - thanks!!!.I use layers a lot(.png) - Is it possible to save GR32 image with layers  to a single GR32 image ( without layers, but visually the same as the one with layers )?